# I'd like to suggest some other way to express disagreement or disapproval of a comment

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I sometimes see what I think are unhelpful, misleading, or off-topic comments on questions, often when they are from new users.

I can see a way to "vote up" a comment, but the only way to express difference is to "flag" it.  Does flagging a comment as "unconstructive, offensive, or spam" go to a moderator for some possible action?  If so, I'd like to suggest some other way to express disagreement or disapproval of a comment, perhaps by a "thumbs down" or "I dissent" action.

I'm not suggesting anything that would affect reputation, just a way to express.  I know I could add an additional comment but I'd rather not get into a debate.

Comment: `Does flagging a comment as "unconstructive, offensive, or spam" go to a moderator for some possible action?` -- Flagged comments are subject to removal by a mod, or removal by the community if the comment gets multiple flags, or removal by one community vote if it contains certain blacklisted words.  Inappropriate comments really should just be removed.

Comment: My idea is to provide something a little less painful than a moderator flag; youse guys are busy doing more important things. Thanks for describing the other ways a comment can be removed, and for making my question more meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

I think the paradigm is that voting up a comment means that you also would have made that comment.  That way you reduce clutter caused by multiple of the same comment.

That's how the `vote for deletion` canned comments seem to work.

That is slightly different from voting up a question or answer, which more or less implies approval or that you believe it to be quality.

---

I do sympathize though.  I, in the past, have wanted to down-vote comments before myself.

Comment: Just curious, but what does `vote for deletion` mean?  Are you talking about the review process?

Comment: @BobDuell Yes i am